# Remove health indicator and code cleanup commands

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I don't like that the [new document health indicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-visual-studio-2019?view=vs-2019#code-cleanup) in Visual Studio 2019 takes some vertical space when horizontal scrollbar is disabled (in Tools → Options → Text Editor → All Languages → ⬚ Show horizontal scroll bar):

How can I disable the display of the Health Indicator and the Code Cleanup command?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable it by going to: Tools | Options -> Text Editor -> General and unchecking the "Show file health indicator" option.

Comment: Thank you!! - Just installed VS2019 and this was driving me nuts! I hate the health indicator widget.